Wrong order of commands execution in Bash script when using command substitution
Goal
I want to write a Bash script in which there are two .sh files:

main.sh - main script, in which I call the subscript subscripts/checksum.sh and write its result to the variable called checksum
subscripts/checksum.sh - script that returns the output of diff command comparing contents of two text files (they differs, so in my example diff command will always return non-zero exit code with some description)

Files structure
$ tree .
.
├── main.sh
└── subscripts
    ├── checksum.sh
    ├── file1.sha512sum.txt
    ├── file1.txt
    ├── file2.sha512sum.txt
    └── file2.txt

2 directories, 6 files

main.sh:
#!/bin/bash


set -e

echo "*** Before checksum"
checksum=$(subscripts/checksum.sh)
echo "*** After checksum"
echo "Checksum value: ${checksum}"

subscripts/checksum.sh:
#/bin/bash


set -e

checksum1=subscripts/file1.sha512sum.txt
checksum2=subscripts/file2.sha512sum.txt

echo "----- Before diff"
if diff_res=$(diff ${checksum1} ${checksum2})
then
    echo "Checksums are equal."
else
    echo "There is a difference between the checksums."
fi
echo "----- After diff"
echo ${diff_res}

Result (wrong)
Executing main.sh gives me below result:
*** Before checksum
*** After checksum
Checksum value: ----- Before diff
There is a difference between the checksums.
1c1 < a5f4d3e657ad3ef1b208e16f47b6d766cf3e2f1db8d6b5c0d2bf0573d10eb2fefcc75c9f91d5f4e047fa9a7d00848911477005015052f7005a2b85eeb8c4eabf file1.txt --- > 576bfc364f00634e8227f71fdf379168e4c3ee013da9eae2bdcdb905746b8514a959a9c01a8f11b8ea62a67ba08a3041a46b8065b73bdaad754e1d6153131896 file2.txt
----- After diff
1c1 < a5f4d3e657ad3ef1b208e16f47b6d766cf3e2f1db8d6b5c0d2bf0573d10eb2fefcc75c9f91d5f4e047fa9a7d00848911477005015052f7005a2b85eeb8c4eabf file1.txt --- > 576bfc364f00634e8227f71fdf379168e4c3ee013da9eae2bdcdb905746b8514a959a9c01a8f11b8ea62a67ba08a3041a46b8065b73bdaad754e1d6153131896 file2.txt

It seems that every command in main.sh has been ran first and after that the commands from subscripts/checksum.sh. Why is that and how can I get the correct result (described below)?
Correct result I want to get
By correct result I mean printing *** Before checksum, then getting into subscripts/checksum.sh and executing all of its command from first to the last one with printing all three echo commands to the console and after that assigning the value of diff_res to checksum in main.sh. The whole action should be ended with the last print which is *** After checksum. In my example the checksum variable should have value:
1c1
< a5f4d3e657ad3ef1b208e16f47b6d766cf3e2f1db8d6b5c0d2bf0573d10eb2fefcc75c9f91d5f4e047fa9a7d00848911477005015052f7005a2b85eeb8c4eabf file1.txt
---
> 576bfc364f00634e8227f71fdf379168e4c3ee013da9eae2bdcdb905746b8514a959a9c01a8f11b8ea62a67ba08a3041a46b8065b73bdaad754e1d6153131896 file2.txt

*** Before checksum
----- Before diff
There is a difference between the checksums.
----- After diff
*** After checksum
Checksum value: 1c1
< a5f4d3e657ad3ef1b208e16f47b6d766cf3e2f1db8d6b5c0d2bf0573d10eb2fefcc75c9f91d5f4e047fa9a7d00848911477005015052f7005a2b85eeb8c4eabf file1.txt
---
> 576bfc364f00634e8227f71fdf379168e4c3ee013da9eae2bdcdb905746b8514a959a9c01a8f11b8ea62a67ba08a3041a46b8065b73bdaad754e1d6153131896 file2.txt



Everything you echo in checksum.sh will be captured by checksum=$(…). Use another fd, stderr for example, to output debugging messages: echo "----- Before diff" >&2

Also, you may want to use quotes, e.g. echo "${diff_res}" to retain line breaks.

By that logic, btw, you should expect differences (as printed by diff) to be show before There is a difference.... If you don't that is because you know that, using diff_res=$(diff...) , instead of printing that difference, you stored output of diff in diff_res. So, why wouldn't you expect the same to happen when you checksum=$(subscript/checksum.sh..., why wouldn't it also store the output of checksum.sh into cheksum rather than printing it?

consider updating the question to explain what you expect to be stored in checksum when all is said and done; from your 'correct' output I'm guessing you want checksum=1c1\n< a5f4d3...\n---\n> 576bfc... ... ???

@markp-fuso I've updated the question regarding my expected result.

See How can I debug a Bash script? and the Debugging section of BashGuide/Practices - Greg's Wiki.

If I understand correctly, you want to see the before/after lines (ignoring other lines) print in this order:
*** Before checksum
----- Before diff
----- After diff
*** After checksum

But it's actually printing in this order:
*** Before checksum
*** After checksum
----- Before diff
----- After diff

This is because of how you've written main.sh. You wrote this:
checksum=$(subscripts/checksum.sh)

This means that the output of checksum.sh, including the Before diff and After diff lines, won't be printed straight away. It will be stored in a variable to be accessed later.
To put it another way, your code is following these steps:

Print *** Before checksum
Run checksum.sh and store its output (the output has Before diff and After diff)
Print *** After checksum
Print Checksum value:
Print the data that was stored from step 2.

So that's why lines are displayed in a different order from what you wanted.
If you want checksum.sh to print Before diff and After diff directly to the terminal, without those lines being stored in a variable, you should change checksum.sh like so:
echo "----- Before diff" >&2
...
echo "----- After diff" >&2

This works because by default, all output goes to stdout which can be stored in variables with $(). But using >&2 sends the output to stderr, which is displayed in the terminal instead of being stored by $().

Thanks for the answer. The most important thing was your explanation that the whole output of the checksum.sh will be stored in variable checksum. Before that I thought that the only last echo will be stored there, and everything preceding that last echo will be printed to the terminal one by one. Now I understand how it works.
